# SQLite floating point condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am executing the following SQLite query on floating point numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM Point where x1 < 12 AND x2 > 12
```

The query works for the `less than` condition but does not evaluate the `greater than` condition properly. It seems to think that a value of `6.12` is greater than 12.

Are there any known issues with evaluating floating point numbers in SQLite?

Comment: can you show some example of your data and specifically the row that contains 6.12?

Comment: I'm guessing it's doing a string comparison - are `x1` and `x2` string columns or numeric columns?

Comment: They are string columns

Comment: What column should they be to use the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your `x2` column is `TEXT` data. You must `CAST` it to float in order to make algebraic comparisons:

```
SELECT * FROM Point where x1 < 12 AND CAST(x2 AS FLOAT) > 12;
```

Better, would be converting all your string data to floating point:

```
UPDATE Point SET x2=CAST(x2 AS FLOAT) WHERE CAST(x2 AS FLOAT)=x2;
```

This will convert all `TEXT` floating point numbers to `FLOAT`.

Comment: or x2+0 also seemed to covert the column to numeric

Comment: Probably at more arithmetic expense. Doing `x2+0` will intrinsically evaluate to `CAST(x2 AS NUMERIC)+0`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are mixing the conditions, your are on a machine that uses the , as decimal separator or you are comparing strings (as suggested by D Stanley in the comments)

[My demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/57964/1) works as expected.